# ruby's "any?" and "all?" methods behaviour on Empty Arrays and Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

First of all I found two useful articles in documentations about these methods:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html
- http://www.globalnerdy.com/2008/01/29/enumerating-rubys-enumerable-module-part-1-all-and-any/

> all?: Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil.
>
> any?: Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil.

But in case of empty arrays and hashes I got:

```
irb(main):004:0> [nil, "car", "bus"].all?
=> false
irb(main):005:0> ["nil", "car", "bus"].all?
=> true
irb(main):006:0> [].all?
=> true
irb(main):007:0> ["nil", "car", "bus"].any?
=> true
irb(main):008:0> [nil, "car", "bus"].any?
=> true
irb(main):009:0> [nil].any?
=> false
irb(main):010:0> [].any?
=> false
```

Can somebody explain to me why empty arrays give me `false` in case of the `any?` method and `true` in case of `all?`?

Comment: In mathematical terms: `any?` is a fold of logical OR whose identity element is `false`. On the other hand `all?` is a fold of logical  AND, whose identity element is `true`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil.

So since the block never gets called, of course it never returns false or nil, thus `all` returns true.

The same goes for `any`:

> The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than
>       false or nil.

Since the block never gets called, it never returns a value other than false or nil, thus `any` returns false.